# how to create an empty doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

if i have the following node class

```
class Node {
 public:
Node() { next = NULL; prev = NULL; }
~Node() {}
 public :
Node *next;
Node *prev;
T data;
 };
```

how do i create an empty linked list in the function

LinkedList::LinkedList()

my linked list classs has the following functions

```
 void append(T item);
T get(int idx);
void insert(int idx, T item);
void map(T (*pf)(T item));
T remove(int index);
int size();
void unshift(T item);
```

Comment: What does your `LinkedList` class look like?

Comment: are you allowed to use `STL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doubly linked lists usually have a reference to the first and (sometimes) last element in the list.

```
Node *first, *last;
```

In your constructor, just set these to `NULL`. Then make an `isEmpty` method which checks for this condition, and you're done.

```
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    first = NULL;
    last = NULL;
}

bool LinkedList::isEmpty()
{
    return (first == NULL) && (last == NULL);
}
```

Comment: i am trying to use the node class that i displayed above

Comment: There are more *magicky* ways of implementing a doubly linked list, like keeping an empty node in the list that is initialized with pointers to itself and that does not take part on the contents of the list. That approach can simplify the code, as there are no needs to check for null in each operation, so the number of code branches gets reduced.

Comment: I've been struggling with this assignment can someone please guide me through this

Answer (score 1):

My solution (from pre-standard days) has always been to have
a `NodeBase` class with the pointers, and derive from that to
add the data.  This allows my `DLList` object to contain
a `NodeBase`, rather than it having to manage the pointers
seperately.  And `NodeBase` always had a constructor which
linked it to nowhere—typically, by setting both pointers
to this, e.g.:

```
struct NodeBase
{
    NodeBase* next;
    NodeBase* prec;
    NodeBase()
        : next(this)
        , prec(this)
    {
    }
    ~NodeBase()
    {
        next->prec = prec;
        prec->next = next;
    }
};
```

Doing so means that there's no clear end of list indicator (the
actual list is circular), so you have to keep track of where you
started when iterating, but it makes so many other operations so
much easier.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers indicate, there's more than one way to do it. Here's an especially peculiar one for your information: although it's *not* portable C so perhaps is better suited to assembly:

```
struct Node {
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};

struct List {
    Node *a;
    Node *b;
    Node *c;
    List : a(tail()), b(0), c(head())
    Node *head() { return (Node *)&a; }
    Node *tail() { return (Node *)&b; }
};
```

So, a struct contains a dummy head node (whose `prev` pointer of course is always 0) and a dummy tail node (whose `next` pointer is always 0), and to save a massive `sizeof(Node*)` bytes storage per list, they *overlap* (which is what makes it non-portable). The overlap isn't essential, you could put two `Node` in the `List` instead of three `Node*`.

This is a useful structure in that it gives you both a "before-the-beginning" and an "after-the-end" node in the list, which means you can perform all of `remove`, `insert_after` and `insert_before` on nodes without reference to the list head at all. In that respect it's like James's circular list, but unlike his you can also check for the ends by looking for the null pointer - also without reference to the head.

File under, "tricks I don't need to play".